# Converting Ruby regex expression to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a text justify function in JavaScript and i'd like to use a regex snippet that worked for my previous Ruby justify function.

The regex is as follows:

`/(?<=\s|\A).{1,#{length}}(?=\s|\z)/`

I'm using this as a template to extract a line of text that's within a specified `length` variable from a larger string that doesn't have line-returns.  The regex ensures that I am capturing all complete words and requisite whitespace within this length and not cutting any words off.

I'd like to create a JavaScript analogue of this regex.

I've tried the basic replace of syntax between Ruby and JS, as follows:

`^\s|\A.{1,length}\s|\z$`

with no success.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/JSVerbalExpressions might be useful

Comment: Lookbehind is not supported and you got it right that you removed it. Now, the anchors `\A` and `\z` are not supported either. You will need to use a constructor notation to declare a dynamic pattern as variable interpolation does not work as in Ruby. Use something like `var length = 5;
    var rx = RegExp("(?:\\s|^)(.{1, " + length + "})(?=\\s|$)", "g");` - your value will be in Group 1 (you will need to run `RegExp#exec` in a while loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookbehind is not supported and you got it right that you removed it. Now, the anchors `\A` and `\z` are not supported either. You will need to use a constructor notation to declare a dynamic pattern as variable interpolation does not work as in Ruby.

Use something like

```js
var length = 5; 
var re = RegExp("(?:\\s|^)(.{1," + length + "})(?=\\s|$)", "g");
var str = 'My cool code on StackOverflow.';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);            // Your value is in Group 1
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>"; // just demo
```